# Restoring marketing taxonomies with Sitecore powershell extenstion

Tags: sitecore-client, powershell-extensions, sitecore-api, sitecore-install-framework

I am trying to automate Sitecore upgrade from 8.1 to 9.0.1.
In Upgrade steps, There is one step restoring deleted marketing taxonomies, which can easily be done with Url navigation and click button on page.
Is it possible to do it with Powershell or using Sitecore API's through which I can create remote session and run command to restore marketing taxonomies?
Any help would be appreciated.